# jQuery AJAX Preloader Problem

Tags: jquery

Hi I am using this script for submitting my form data to php page its working well...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#preloader').hide();     
    $('#preloader')
        .ajaxStart(function(){
            $(this).show();
        }).ajaxStop(function(){
            $(this).hide();
        });                                                 
    $('#form form').submit(function(){
        $('#content').empty();
        $.get('data.php', $(this).serialize(), function(data){                          
            $('#content').html(data);
        });         
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

But the problem is if jquery fails to load or if javascript is turned off in browser the hide function continues to display what i need is ... the loading div only shows up if jquery loads successfully or is there any other trick for doing that Thankyou...

Answer (score 0):

Also hide element with CSS, example:

```
<div id="preloader" style="display:none;"></div>
```

So if JS is disabled then CSS will work, and if JS is enabled both will work which is not a problem.